# Automatic resending of page information

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I've added this code to the master page page_load event to prevent caches. (got it from random sources.)

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(False)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

After processing information in the masterpage, say, adding two numbers and displaying the sum, when i navigate away from the masterpage and want to go back using the browser's back button, the resend dialog box appears with 'resend' and 'cancel' buttons. clicking resend loads the masterpage together with its previous information(the sum), and cancel does nothing,  What i am trying to do is to hide or disable the dialog box and automatically select 'resend' so that when the user clicks the browser's back button he is automatically redirected to the previous masterpage without the dialog box appearing. 
Or is there any method with similar effect. Or is this even possible. please reply.. newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

The browser shows this message because your page `POST`s back to the server when the button is clicked. It sends the input values (the two numbers to be summed), and the server responds with the result. When you click 'Back', the browser warns you because often it's a bad idea to `POST` the data again. Making an online purchase, for example.

You can get around this by putting a `Response.Redirect(...)` in the `Button_Click` handler - this sends a new `GET` request. I can show C# code, I don't know VB.NET sorry:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (IsPostBack) return;
  int num1, num2;
  if (Int32.TryParse(Session["num1"], out num1) && Int32.TryParse(Session["num2"], out num2)) {
    txtNum1.Text = num1.ToString();
    txtNum2.Text = num2.ToString();
    lblSum.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();
  } 
}

internal void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Session["num1"] = txtNum1.Text;
  Session["num2"] = txtNum2.Text;
  Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
}
```